¿Como puedo enlazar dos bindingsource a un datagridview? vb.net 2.0
Alguien me puede decir como asociar dos bindingsource a un solo datagridview? El proyecto esta desarrollado en vb.net 2.0 (2005) y necesito aplicar un filtro y que la misma se visualice en un datagridview (cuyo origen de datos es un binding de la tabla cliente). El problema surge que el dato que necesito filtrar no se encuentra en la tabla clientes, sino en otra tabla (cuya relacion con la tabla clientes es cliente_id). Es por eso que se me ocurrió tratar de colocar dos binding a un datagridview . Slds
